Jest, typeOfEnv is node, polyfill with node-fetch, complains about require() when clearly using import
Node v16.20.2
package.json:
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "baffled-i-tell-you",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@cloudflare/wrangler": "^1.12.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}

babel.config.js:
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
      ],
    },
  },
};


jest.config.js:
const config = {
  testEnvironment: './tests/config/FixGlobalsEnvironment.js',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  },
  globals: {
    addEventListener: () => {} // Used in main piece of code, but not for testing
  }
};

module.exports = config;

FixGlboalsEnvironment.js:
import fetch, {Headers, Request, Response} from "node-fetch";
import NodeEnvironment from 'jest-environment-node';

export default class FixGlobalsEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

        this.global.fetch = fetch;
        this.global.Headers = Headers;
        this.global.Request = Request;
        this.global.Response = Response;
    }
}

Result when executing yarn test:
    Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/joy/.../node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from /home/joy/.../tests/config/FixGlobalsEnvironment.js not supported.

    Instead change the require of index.js in /home/joy/.../tests/config/FixGlobalsEnvironment.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

       6 |         super(...args);
       7 |
    >  8 |         this.global.fetch = fetch;
         |                                          ^
       9 |         this.global.Headers = Headers;
      10 |         this.global.Request = Request;
      11 |         this.global.Response = Response;

      at Object.newLoader [as .js] (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:121:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/config/FixGlobalsEnvironment.js:8:42)
      at Module._compile (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:117:24)
      at Object.newLoader [as .js] (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:121:7)
          at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at async ScriptTransformer.requireAndTranspileModule (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:798:22)

I am confused at the message: Instead change the require of index.js in /home/joy/.../tests/config/FixGlobalsEnvironment.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules. 
Clearly I have messed up the configuration between Babel and Jest, but I don't know where I have messed it up.

I am using the polyfill solution because "node" environment doesn't have Headers, Response, Request. Main code tested is not running in a browser environment. When I try running this with default "node" environment:


Using node-fetch v2 I get this error: (when I have polyfilled it...)
TypeError: Class constructor Request cannot be invoked without 'new'

       8 |         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       9 |
    > 10 |         return new Request(url, {
         |                ^
      11 |             method: 'GET',
      12 |             headers
      13 |         });

      at mockConstructor.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:794:25)
      at getRequestMock (tests/index.test.js:10:16)
      at getRequestMock (tests/index.test.js:23:45)
      at call (tests/index.test.js:2:1)
      at Generator.tryCatch (tests/index.test.js:2:1)
      at Generator._invoke [as next] (tests/index.test.js:2:1)



The cherry on top, if I remove everything, and leave environment on "node" but run the test from my IDE (PHPStorm)... it works great, all test pass accordingly, no problems with set up.

I have added transformIgnorePatterns: [], to my jest.config.js as I saw others do, but it did not work.

I have removed also removed jest.config.js in favour of only having babel.config.js. Of course I lose the possibility of doing the polyfill in a nice way through jest.config.js so I have to create a file that has this code (I import the file as the first import on my tests).
import fetch, {Headers, Request, Response} from "node-fetch";

global.addEventListener = () => {};
global.fetch = fetch;
global.Headers = Headers;
global.Request = Request;
global.Response = Response;

Still doesn't work, error is now:
 TypeError: Class constructor Request cannot be invoked without 'new'

      12 |         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      13 |
    > 14 |         return new Request(url, {
         |                ^
      15 |             method: 'GET',
      16 |             headers
      17 |         });

      at mockConstructor.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:794:25)
      at getRequestMock (tests/index.test.js:14:16)
      at getRequestMock (tests/index.test.js:27:45)




You may have written import, but you're using the default (implicit) "type": "commonjs" and transpiling (via Babel) to CommonJS and using require. So the error's about require.

If I understood correctly, then setting "type": "node" , in jest.config would be the fix, right? (Because that's not working ... ) :( @jonrsharpe

ps: I had that wrong, it was type: "module" in package.json ,no? (It doesn't work either)

I never found a way to "properly" fix this, so instead I opted for this:
import fetch, { Headers, Request, Response } from "node-fetch";
import NodeEnvironment from "jest-environment-node";
// This file is FixGlobalsEnvironment.js
export default class FixGlobalsEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    // Jest is not loading in the global object the Fetch API
    // variables , so we have o load them manually
    this.global.fetch = fetch;
    this.global.Headers = Headers;
    this.global.Request = Request;
    this.global.Response = Response;
    this.global.Response.redirect = (url, code) => new Response(url, code);
  }
}

And in jest.config.js
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  testEnvironment: './tests/config/FixGlobalsEnvironment.js',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js)$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [],
  globals: {
    addEventListener: () => {}
  }
};

module.exports = config;

Maybe I'll find another solution, but at the moment this is it.
